# Difference in SSIS flat file width even when the number of characters are same

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have two flat files and the number of characters in both files are 1294, however when I am running those files through an SSIS package, the package read the width of file one as 1294 and file two as 1295. There is a difference of black spots at the end of each row in the file, screenshots below for better explanation:-

File 1:-

[image]

File 2:-

[image]

As seen above there is one blackspot at the end of file one and two black spots at the end of file two even though the row length in both files is 1294 but because of the extra black spot in file two the package is reading it is as 1295.

What is that at the end of the file and what could be the reason for this? I cannot figure this, I am working with SSIS for the first time.

**EDIT:** I opened both the files in Hex editor and again in the Hex editor I see 1 dot at the end of file 1 and 2 dots at the end of file 2. However these dots are not present when I open these files in notepad.

File 1 in hex editor:-
[image]

File 2 in hex editor:-
[image]

Comment: Use a hex editor to inspect the files, e.g.: the "Show Hexdump" extension in Visual Studio Code. Most likely one of the files uses linefeed end-of-line characters (0x0A) and the other uses carriage return linefeed character pairs (0x0D 0x0A).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have opened both the files in an online hex editor but I dont know what I should be looking for?

Comment: Look at the bottom right - one has 0a and the other has 0d 0a. So the line endings are 1 byte and 2 bytes respectively.  <cr><lf> vs <lf>.